# How the right way to rollback migration with Entity Framework

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, visual-studio, entity-framework-6

I'm very newbie with EF and migration. I'm trying to make a rollback with the command, to run the Down method

```
update-database -TargetMigration MyLastMigration
```

Output result

```
Target database is already at version 201701031905415_MyLastMigration.
```

How can I execute the Down method of MyLastMigration?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your target migration should be the migration immediately previous to the one that you want to rollback:

```
update-database -SourceMigration MyLastMigration -TargetMigration MigrationPreviousToMyLastMigration
```

The `SourceMigration` parameter is optional in your case, as you have not applied any migration after `MyLastMigration`.

To check the name of the previous migration you can use `Get-Migrations`, that returns the list of migrations applied to your database.

**Edit:** as Ivan Stoev says in the comments, the `SourceMigration` parameter can only be included together with the parameter `Script`, so it does not make sense in this scenario. The right command would be like this:

```
update-database -TargetMigration MigrationPreviousToMyLastMigration
```

Comment: Not sure `-SourceMigration` is allowed (the help says *Only valid with -Script.*), but the rest is correct. +1

Comment: @IvanStoev You are right, if we are not generating a script the source migration can only be the actual current migration applied to the database. Thanks for the correction! I'll edit the answer.